# Expressing $\displaystyle\int_1^x S(u) \mathrm{d}u$ in terms of elementary function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, integration

Let's suppose we have the following series 
$$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{n+1}$$
then I need to express $\displaystyle\int_1^x S(u) \mathrm{d}u$ in terms of elementary function. Some hints, suggestions ?

Thanks!!!

Sis.

Comment: So $x$ is some number larger than 1?

Comment: @Yimin: I posted the whole problem's text. There is nothing more than that.

Comment: We know that $\log(1+x^2) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{x^{2n}}{n} $, so if your $|x|<1$, then your formula is $\dfrac{\log(1+x^2)-x^2}{x^2}$

Comment: The power series for $S(x)$ does not converge for $|x| \gt 1$, so it seems the question is meaningful only for $-1 \lt x \lt 1$.

Comment: @Yimin: Ah, right! Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have 
$$\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n},$$
so we find
$$x^2S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(x^2)^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(x^2)^n}{n}-x^2=\log(1+x^2)-x^2.$$

Now, we inegrate by parts, we find
\begin{align}\int_1^xS(u)du&=\int_1^x(\frac{\log(1+u^2)}{u^2}-1)du\\&=\frac{-1}{2x}(2\log(x^2+1)-(2-\pi+2\log2)x-4x\arctan x+2x^2)\end{align}

Comment: Maybe you'll want to simplify to $2\tan^{-1}(x) - \frac{\log(1+x^2)}{x} - x - \frac{\pi}{2} + \log(2) + 1$.

Comment: Yes, if you want.

Comment: It's interesting that the singularity of $S(x)$ at $x = \pm 1$ disappears after the integration.

Comment: At $1$, ther's not a problem since S is well defined in this point, but at $-1$ it's true, the singularity disappears.

Comment: Well, $S$ is an even function, so $S(1)=S(-1)=\log(2)-1$, but the series expansion diverges beyond that.  So $S$ must have a singularity, in the complex analysis sense, at some $|z|=1$.

Comment: Ah, you're right, thanks for this comment

Answer (score 4):

There are two elementary approaches, recognize and integrate, or integrate and recognize.  We take the second path.

Your sum goes from $n=1$ to infinity, but if it is a good little mathematical sum, it probably really wants to start at $n=0$. If it stubbornly insists on $n=1$, we can subtract appropriately at the end.  When we integrate
$$\sum_0^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{n+1}$$
term by term, we get
$$\sum_0^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(n+1)(2n+1)},$$
or equivalently (partial fractions)
$$\sum_0^\infty 2(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} - \sum_0^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{n+1}.$$
The first sum is $2\arctan x$.  The second sum (for $x\ne 0$) can be rewritten as 
$\dfrac{1}{x}\displaystyle\sum_0^\infty (-1)^n \dfrac{(x^2)^{n+1}}{n+1}$. This is $\dfrac{1}{x}\log(1+x^2)$.